# How to import existing resources to terraform in a separate subdirectory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created some resources including VPC, ... in AWS using the console a long time ago and now I want to import them into Terraform. I already made a structure for my project like:

```
└── project_xxx
    ├── main.tf
    ├── modules
    │   ├── module_foo
    │   │   ├── main.tf
    │   │   ├── outputs.tf
    │   │   └── variables.tf
    │   ├── module_bar
    │   │   ├── main.tf
    │   │   ├── outputs.tf
    │   │   └── variables.tf
    │   ...
    ├── outputs.tf
    ├── provider.tf
    ├── README.md
    ├── terraform.tfvars
    ├── variables.tf
    └── versions.tf
```

but when I try to import resources in their modules, Terraform gives an Error and asks for creating them in root directory.
Any suggestions?

for example:
in modules/module_foo/main.tf, I have the following codes:

```
  resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy = "default"

  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}
```

Then: in the root, I execute the following commands:

```
terraform init
terraform plan # it shows one resource will be added
terraform import aws_vpc.main vpc-xxx1234
```

Then I get the Error, that the resource must be created in root.

Comment: It would be helpful to add the command you are trying, the name of the resource you are trying to import as well as the error output itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are trying to import resources into a module, the syntax for import is slightly different compared to the case when modules are not used. In this case it should be something like:

```
terraform import module.module_foo.aws_vpc.main vpc-xxx1234
```

More information is available here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/import.html#example-import-into-module.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this a while ago, not exactly your use case but something similar so I will drop what I found here, perhaps it helps someone else.
I would recommend using terraformer for these cases, it helps to have a good sense of your existing infrastructure and it generates a state for you, it is not bulletproof but indeed helpful https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer: CLI tool to generate terraform files from existing infrastructure (reverse Terraform). Infrastructure to Code

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. In this case, you have to create a module in the main.tf file of the root directory.

```
module "aws_vpc" {
  source = "./modules/module_foo"
```

And then import the resources using this command:

```
terraform import module.aws_vpc.aws_vpc.main vpc-xxx1234
```